# Accessing vectors and exporting data to a file

Tags: c++

I've just picked up this code that opens a raw file, reads the data and stores it in a vector. Now, i have a Java background and after reading up on some basics, i feel that i understand how things work in C++ a little better, but i haven't come across the format of the file readers function before...

The aim is to get the data stored in the vector that was created in the function and print it out to a CSV file. In java, no problem. What i want is some pointers and some good resources that can help someone who is a complete beginner with C++. Just to repeat, i'm looking for tips, not for answers.

```
//Set file name and path    
std::string filename = "Betty.raw";

//Open binary file for reading
std::ifstream myfile(filename.c_str(), std::ios::in | std::ios::binary);
if (myfile.is_open()) {

    unsigned char c = 0;
    float f = 0;

    //Loop through data X changes first/fastest.
    for (unsigned int iz = 0; iz < mZMax; iz++)
        for (unsigned int iy = 0; iy < mYMax; iy++)
            for (unsigned int ix = 0; ix < mXMax; ix++) {

                //Initialise empty vector
                my::Vec3f vec = my::Vec3f();

                //Read x then y then z and store in vec (vector)
                //Data needs converting to float from char and adjusted
                myfile.read((char *)&c, 1);
                f = (float)c;
                vec.x = f/255-0.5;

                myfile.read((char *)&c, 1);
                f = (float)c;
                vec.y = f/255-0.5;

                myfile.read((char *)&c, 1);
                f = (float)c;
                vec.z = f/255-0.5;

                //Store vector in datastructure
                mData[iz][iy][ix] = vec;

            }

main() {


char delimiter = ", ";

for(unsigned x=0; x < mData[ix]; x++) {
    for(unsigned y=0; y < mData[iy]; y++) {
        for(unsigned z=0; z < mData[iz]; z++) {
            cout << x << delimiter << y << delimiter <<  z << endl;
}

    //Close the file when finished
    myfile.close();
}
```

Comment: I dont know exactly what problem are you haveing, but I believe you are looking for this: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/operator%3E%3E/ which allows you to read as many byte needed for a given data type

Comment: The problem i'm having is accessing the vector that's been created, then exporting the information in the vector to a text or csv file.

Comment: Hard to give tips with this little information. `fileout << mData[iz][iy][ix] <<','` could be all you need, and it could be a heck of a lot more complicated. Could you give us an example of what you would like the output to look like and more about `mData` and `Vec3f `?

Comment: Accessing `my::Vec3f vec` from where?

Comment: So, i'm assuming i'd be creating a main() function, that access the vector and prints out the x, y and z values into 3 columns (x, y and z) into a CSV. Didn't think it would be this complicated haha

Comment: vec3f (from what i believe) creates an empty vector and the three for loops create the values of iz, iy and ix, then stores them in mData. So ideally, access mData in the main() and print those files to a CSV

Comment: You know how to access the vector. 3 nested loops, just like in the code you have. Then write with formated output instead of reading in binary mode.

Comment: @super Hey man, cheers for that, that was really helpful. I've edited my code and made a little function that prints out the vector (if it works), let me know if its correct. Then all that's left is to create a function to print to a csv. Cheers man

Comment: @super As i said, i'm new to C++, just want to make sure the syntax is correct and everything. Constructive feedback is good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To acces the vector you can simply recycle your first 3 nested loops.

```
std::ofstream output("blah.csv");

if (!output.is_open())
    //error, abandon ship!!!

char delimiter = ','; // char can only hold 1 character, and uses ' not "
// Alternative if you want spaces aswell
// std::string delimiter = ", ";

for (unsigned int iz = 0; iz < mZMax; iz++)
    for (unsigned int iy = 0; iy < mYMax; iy++)
        for (unsigned int ix = 0; ix < mXMax; ix++)
            output << mData[iz][iy][ix].x << delimiter << mData[iz][iy][ix].y << delimiter << mData[iz][iy][ix].z << '\n';
```

This assumes that mData holds objects of `my::Vec3f` and that you want the output in the csv to be your normalized float values between 0-1.

Another good thing to improve in your code would be to check for read fail/success instead of using a fixed buffer size with `mZMax` ect. Then replace mData with a dynamic container like a `std::vector`.

Comment: Cheers man, can this be done is the same function as the first set of nested loops? Or am i right in saying that this will be called in the main?

Comment: Both could work. For the sake of encapsulation I would go for the latter, but if this is the one and only task of the program all options that gets the job done I guess.